# NVIDIA Optimus limitations

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, directx, optimus, igp

Based on a [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105003/d3d12-device-not-supported) on **gamedev.stackexchange**, 
I was wondering, if there were any limitations to the *NVIDIA Optimus Technology*, regarding the supported versions of *DirectX*.
More specifically, if the GPU is limited by the supported DirectX runtime of the IGP.

According to the *NVIDIA Optimus Flow* (**Figure 6** of the *[Optimus Whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/object/lo_optimus_whitepapers.html)*), my assumption was, that this is not the case, since the IGP is only used to display the Image, when rendering with the GPU.

However, my system fails to create a D3D12 device, even though, it "should" be supported, at least by the GPU (DX12 runtime, feature level 11.0). Thus, the question, of whether the IGP is limiting the supported *DirectX* version, when running in an *Optimus* environment, or, if it may be an issue related to the drivers (which are all up to date, at this moment) or the hardware itself.

My system:
Windows 10, 64-bit
Intel Core i5 M460 with Intel HD Graphics
NVIDIA GeForce GT540M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research, I finally found the reason for this. Apparently, Fermi-based GPUs do not support DirectX12 yet.
["[They] will gain support for DirectX 12 ... later this year"](http://www.geforce.com/whats-new/articles/windows-10-game-ready-nvidia-geforce-gtx-driver-released).

Hopefully, this won't take too long.